# Issue with installing apache superset on EKS

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, amazon-eks, apache-superset

I have created an EKS cluster with ALB setup. I tried installing superset by following the steps provided in https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/running-on-kubernetes/

my-values.yaml

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  ingressClassName: ~
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: instance
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    ## Extend timeout to allow long running queries.
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "300"
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "300"
    # nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "300"
  path: /
  pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  hosts:
    - chart-example.local
  tls: []
  extraHostsRaw: []
  #  - secretName: chart-example-tls
  #    hosts:
  #      - chart-example.local
```

When I am running `helm upgrade --install --values my-values.yaml superset superset/superset --timeout 10m30s`, it takes a lot of time and returns

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: post-upgrade hooks failed: 1 error occurred:
    * timed out waiting for the condition
```

and when I run

```
[ec2-user@ip-1**-**-**-*** ~]$ kubectl get pods
NAME                               READY   STATUS       RESTARTS        AGE
superset-7866fcc8b4-tcpk4          0/1     Init:0/1     8 (6m53s ago)   33m
superset-init-db-6q9dp             0/1     Init:Error   0               5m24s
superset-init-db-7hqz4             0/1     Init:Error   0               7m48s
superset-init-db-jt87x             0/1     Init:Error   0               12m
superset-init-db-rt85r             0/1     Init:Error   0               10m
superset-init-db-zptz6             0/1     Init:Error   0               2m40s
superset-postgresql-0              0/1     Pending      0               33m
superset-redis-master-0            1/1     Running      0               33m
superset-worker-748db75bf7-9kzfp   0/1     Init:0/1     8 (6m56s ago)   33m
```

I am new to kubernetes and this is new to me. Please help!

Edit:1
Added EBS CSI driver and Storage Class and went ahead with superset installation. Ran the following commands. Attaching responses

```
kubectl get pods
    NAME                               READY   STATUS     RESTARTS       AGE
    superset-7866fcc8b4-q59nd          0/1     Init:0/1   4 (109s ago)   13m
    superset-init-db-gq9b9             0/1     Pending    0              13m
    superset-postgresql-0              0/1     Pending    0              13m
    superset-redis-master-0            1/1     Running    0              13m
    superset-worker-748db75bf7-n7t2r   0/1     Init:0/1   5 (91s ago)    13m

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-23-209 ~]$ kubectl logs superset-worker-748db75bf7-n7t2r
Defaulted container "superset" out of: superset, wait-for-postgres-redis (init)
Error from server (BadRequest): container "superset" in pod "superset-worker-748db75bf7-n7t2r" is waiting to start: PodInitializing

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-23-209 ~]$ kubectl logs superset-7866fcc8b4-q59nd
Defaulted container "superset" out of: superset, wait-for-postgres (init)
Error from server (BadRequest): container "superset" in pod "superset-7866fcc8b4-q59nd" is waiting to start: PodInitializing

kubectl describe pod superset-postgresql-0
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                 ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  4m20s (x4 over 16m)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 Too many pods. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running PostgreSQL, and you're using EKS 1.23 or higher, you'll need to install a CSI driver, e.g. the [EBS CSI driver](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver). Starting with 1.23, EKS no longer ships with a storage driver (the in-tree driver was deprecated). After installing the CSI driver, create a default storage class. Your pods should start shortly thereafter. If you're new to Kubernetes, I'd recommend installing the CSI driver through [EKS addons](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managing-add-ons.html).

Comment: I was of the impression that the helm chart will automatically install postgress pod as well. I guess I was wrong. Let me try this out

Comment: Not PostgreSQL, the CSI driver that PostgreSQL depends on for persistence. I doubt the chart installs a CSI driver.

Comment: So correct me if i am wrong, 1. Install the ebs csi driver on eks. 2. Create a PV, PVC on eks. 3. Run the superset helm chart- which will install the postgres pod and the remaining superset pods?

Comment: I don't think you'll have to create the PV or PVC. Check the chart for PostgreSQL to see if it creates those objects. After you've installed the CSI driver and default storage class, the PostgreSQL pods should start. If they don't start immediately, try restarting them.

Comment: I tried adding the ebs csi driver and followed the steps on the above superset link. The postgres pod is always in pending state. Ran a describe and got   Warning  FailedScheduling  2s (x4 over 12m)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 Too many pods. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 No preemption victims found for incoming pod.

Comment: I have added the changes under Edit-1

Comment: Look at the logs for the EBS CSI driver and see if there are errors.

Comment: Ran kubectl get pods -A and the ebs-csi-controller pods are in ready state. kubectl -n kube-system rollout status deployment ebs-csi-controller
deployment "ebs-csi-controller" successfully rolled out

Comment: The EBS CSI driver has 2 components. The controller and the daemonset. You need both. Check to see whether there are any errors in the logs (for both).

Comment: I think something is wrong with the csi driver. Tried https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/ebs-sample-app.html and its throwing 0/1 nodes are available: 1 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims. preemption: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 Preemption is not helpful for scheduling. Let me recreate a cluster with ebs csi addon properly.

Answer (score 1):

You got to inspect the logs of these pods; to see why it is failing; But initially, seems

- Postgres bitnami chart has to be installed as part of superset installation process.
- For some reason, **postgres pod is pending** (*most probably because it cannot create a persistent volume; might be something else*). You can know by running `kubectl describe pod superset-postgresql-0` and `kubectl logs superset-init-db-6q9dp -c init`
- Superset pods cannot start until the postgres is up, which make sense to have it in the init container of your pod not to start your app unless DB is ready. You can inspect that by running logs on one of the logs `kubectl logs superset-7866fcc8b4-tcpk4 -c init`.

That is my guess; You can know for sure by following the above kubectl commands I provided.

Long story short, superset installation to work **needs to have postgres started** as per of init checks before it actually starts; **postgres is not**, that's why superset is failing. Why postgres is not starting ? Check the logs.